# bind data from WS to "DevEx ASP.NET GridView" and to use CRUD operations on the data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, gridview, devexpress

I am trying to fill a ASP.NET gridview with a  webservice and try to do the CRUD operations. I found the link​ very usefull but I have a problem.

When I try to update row, I can reach the new values, so I can send the new values to webservice and update the database. My problem is that when I click the "edit"​ link on the row, I enter the new text and then I click the "update" link. Then the grid doesnt get out of the edit mode to read mode, and it displays an error message something like  "operation is not supported", it gives the error message in Turkish, so I am not sure what it says in English.

[image]

How can I prevent that error message and get out of the edit mode when I click the "update" link ?​

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing:

- Handle the ASPxGridView.RowUpdating event;
- Get a datasource from the corresponding storage;
- Retrieve the edited data item. Use the e.Keys dictionary for this purpose;
- Edit the data item properties;
- Save the storage changes;
- Set the eventArgs e.Cancel property to "True" to cancel an updating operation;
- Call the ASPxGridView.CancelEdit method to close the EditForm.